# Mysql Count Query with value condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the table `Student` as defined below:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|id               |paperId          |readFlag         |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|1                |1                |1                |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|2                |2                |1                |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|3                |3                |1                |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|4                |1                |0                |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|5                |2                |1                |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|6                |3                |1                |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|7                |4                |1                |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I want to know how many `paperId`s have either exactly one record or two records, where both the records have `readFlag` set to `1`.

For the example data, the answer is 3 (`paperId`'s 2, 3, and 4).

How would I write a query to do this?

EDIT:

I don't want to use subquery, because I have millions of records and it takes too much time to execute subquery.

Comment: And please edit the question to show any attempts you have made to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: good luck on your homework

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(paperId)) from STUDENT 
        WHERE paperId NOT IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(paperId) 
        from STUDENT where readFlag = 0);
```

OR

```
 SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(paperID)) from student) - 
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(paperID)) from student where readFlag=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

smth. like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(paperID)  
FROM Student  
WHERE readFlag=1  
GROUP BY paperId
```

Comment: hi..Thanks for your reply and time, but this query will give group wise count, not total and also num of records are also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
SELECT 
    paperID
FROM
    student
WHERE
    id > 0
AND readFlad > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select count(distinct(paperId)) as Winners 
  from table
where readFlag = 1 
and paperId not in(select distinct paperId where readFlag = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I got solution

```
select 
distinct s1.paperId 
from Student s1
left join Student s2
on 
(s1.paperId = s2.paperId)
and 
s2.readFlag = 1
group by s1.paperId having sum(s1.readFlag) >1 or count(s1.readFlag)=1 ;
```